# Share live list between ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a MVVM C# project where I have a void launched when the MainViewModel is opened and starts parsing data from the web and adds each item as they are found into my BindableCollection named foundItemsList.

I would like a live feed of that list between the Main ViewModel and the second ViewModel I have named AddItemViewModel.

How is this achievable because when I try to send the data, it will only send the data of the list as it is when I click on the button to open the AddItemViewModel and does not consider any items found after I have opened the AddItemViewModel.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you post sample code?

Comment: What do you mean on "live feed"?

Comment: Live as in: when a new item is added then the list should update in all views and viewmodels at once

Answer (score 1):

There are the `Event Aggregator` and `Mediator` patterns which are common place when wanting to provide communication between `ViewModels` in `MVVM`.  These essentially provide a `Publish` and `Subscribe` mechanism to pass data between `ViewModels`.

Alternatively you could have a parent `ViewModel` that your `MainViewModel` and `AddItemViewModel` derive from and which implements the functionality surrounding your `BindableCollection`.

Another alternative would be to expose an `event` in your `MainViewModel` that the `AddItemViewModel` can `subscribe` to so as to be informed when the `BindableCollection` in `MainViewModel` changes.  This would mean making your `AddItemViewModel` aware of `MainViewModel` which may, or may not, be acceptable for you.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would really advice you to implement such logic is with adding some **Service** part to your application.
The service must be responsible for any operations related to the data manipulation (meaning, the data of business logic). So, if you need some thing to get from server (or any other data changes) -- you call some method of the Service, like "GiveMeTheData()" (it can be also *Asyncronous*).

That would allow you to decouple responsibilities of code parts which (besides of easier code reading) would give you an abitility for easier testing of different parts.

---

So, as for handling the both ViewModels to update -- generally you just *subscribe for something like 'OnNewDataArriving' event, which every of the ViewModels subscribing to your Service* (on their initialization). *But this is a conceptual explanation.*

To speak of *real life implementation* -- different ways to do that possible (also, dependently on framework you use to manage MVVM (if you don't still, you really should considering that)).

So:

- if you are using something like **[MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross)**, you can use subscribe on certain messages sent through the application: in our case the Server would send something like "Some new data of some certain data type has arrived" message, and every ViewModel (if subscribed to that type of messages) would be notified and changed its content accordingly.
- alternatively, you can implement all that logic with using **[Rx (Reactive Extensions)](http://www.introtorx.com/)**: you just define some IObservable collections (as a source of data for every ViewModel you need) (that collection should rather also be located in your service (if not in service, there must still be something like "**Repository**" which would include those collections (and data generally).